# Running an HTTP Web Application on Android

Tags: android, web, wifi

I have a scenario where I should connect and disconnect to several WiFi endpoints from my web application and at the same time expose some REST API's. Since I come from a JVM background, I started writing a Java web application using Spring Boot and when I started to try writing WiFi connections / disconnections, I realized that it is not so easy and I had to do some ugly hacks. So I ditched the JVM and I thought that I could explot Android for this and this API from Android is exactly what I need:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

I now have a Android device and this device would run as my primary server where I would like to run a Web Application that would eventually serve REST styled end points and at the same time manage my WiFi connections. I want to be able to use the Android SDK with which I could connect and disconnect to several WiFi networks, but I'm not sure as to how I could have a HTTP server that runs on Android where I can implement my classical CRUD style web application like I do in Spring Boot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Traditionally, Android has not been a server platform. Android Things will change that to an extent. Even to the extent that Android *does* start becoming more accommodating for servers, most JVM-based Web app server solutions are designed for **much** bigger environments than a single Android app. You'll be lucky to get [a basic HTTP/WebSockets server](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync#androidasync-also-lets-you-create-simple-http-servers).

Comment: You can use `NanoHttpD` to make your own webserver. For the rest i dont understand that a webserver should mess around with wifi connections. `I want to be able to use the Android SDK with which I could connect and disconnect to several WiFi networks`. Why would you do that? And what does it have to do with building a webserver? Able to use the Android ASDK? On a PC ? Unclear what you want.

Comment: I want to be able to connect and disconnect to WiFi networks based on the request that I get from a client device!